# Using Scrapy with a List of Keyword

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a csv file contains book names with single columns and 1000 row. I need the crawl author and published year on the next columns. Can i do this with Scrapy? Is there any document to share with me?

Thanks for now.

Book_Name;Author;Published_Date

don quijote;;

name of the rose;;

oliver twist;;

Edit: I tried to find data from "https://isbndb.com". I wonder if scrapy is suitable for this job.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Yes you can do it. Sadly we don't provide documentations. Try to search for the documentations and start solving the problem. When you encounter any issues, update your question / post a new question with details about what you've tried and what errors you get.

Answer (score 1):

Scrapy is used for Webscraping.
In your case you could simply use [CSV files and Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)